# Passing events back to a Dialog's host

Tags: android, button, dialog

I have a simple user interface with a dialog opened by clicking the "plus" button in the action bar of my main activity. Once inserted a string and clicked "continue", I wish was created a button at the top right under the action bar (in the main activity) and that over the button to appear the same string that I put in the dialog.

I state that I have followed the SDK android guide at the Dialog section but I can not get what I want.

Here is my interface with dialog:

[image]

and here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IProjectDialFrag {

    private ProjectDialogFragment projectDialFrag = new ProjectDialogFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //TODO
                return true;
            case R.id.filters:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_new:
                return true;
            case R.id.add_button:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
            case R.id.add_project:
                projectDialFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "projectDialog");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        String projectName = editText.getText().toString();
        //TODO

    }

}
```

IProjectDialFrag:

```
public interface IProjectDialFrag {

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);

}
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class ProjectDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private IProjectDialFrag iProjDialFrag;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         AlertDialog.Builder createProjectAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

         createProjectAlert.setTitle("Create Project");

         LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

         createProjectAlert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_dialog_fragment, null))

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.conti_nue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //iProjDialFrag.onDialogPositiveClick(ProjectDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    iProjDialFrag.onDialogNegativeClick(ProjectDialogFragment.this);

                }
            });

         return createProjectAlert.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        iProjDialFrag = (IProjectDialFrag) activity;
    }

}
```

If you need the XML layout to understand better, please tell me.

Thank you everyone

Comment: I think you'll need to make your action bar with a custom view. If you're using the menus, there's no view you have access to to change the actionbar.  If you create a custom view, then you have control of all icons and their states

Answer (score 0):

If I got the Question Right, not the Communication is the Problem, but the Creation of your Button and your Text.

If so, you need to Add those Dynamically to your Layout. To do so, create a container (e.G a LinearLayout) and give it an ID. In my Example Code I Assume that the ID is called `buttonContainer`

```
private void addButton(String text) {
    Button newBtn = new Button(this);
    TextView newTV = new TextView(this);
    newTV.setText(text);

    View container = findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer);
    container.addView(newTV);
    container.addView(newBtn);
}
```

Comment: Ok but where do I use this method? In the main activity? Other question..the layout you consider describes the just the button?